# Remove alpha channel from UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, alpha, cgcontext

I use the following method to get a decompressed uiimage from file system. However the UIImageView is colored as red when I turn on the color blended layer, even though the UIImageView is set to Opaque.

The images on file system don't have alpha channel. I tried set CGContextSetAlpha(bitmapContext, 1), but still has blended layer.

Anyone know how to remove alpha channel when using CGContextDrawImage?

```
- (UIImage *)decompressedImage
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = self.CGImage;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, CGImageGetWidth(imageRef), CGImageGetHeight(imageRef));
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                       rect.size.width,
                                                       rect.size.height,
                                                       CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                                       CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef),
                                                       CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                                       kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little
                                                       );
    // kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little are the bit flags required
    //  so that the main thread doesn't have any conversions to do.

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmapContext, rect, imageRef);

    CGImageRef decompressedImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
    UIImage* decompressedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:decompressedImageRef
                                                     scale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]
                                               orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    CGImageRelease(decompressedImageRef);
    CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);

    return decompressedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the options for the context, try the option

```
kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast
```

or

```
kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
```

Depending on if you are using RGBA or ARGB

ie,

```
CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                       rect.size.width,
                                                       rect.size.height,
                                                       CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                                       CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef),
                                                       CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                                       kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little
                                                       );
```

Comment: It works. Though I didn't much performance improvement, happy to see the red marks gone. Thanks.

Comment: @Jensen Removing the alpha channel doesn't really give you performance boosts, because they basically fill it in for you when creating a UIImage. You get the boost of smaller compressed images though so its still a good optimization :)

Comment: I just found that using kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast consumes much more memory than using kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst. Do you have any ideas what causes this?

Comment: @Jensen My guess is that when you used kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst it treated your image 1/4 smaller, since it counts 4 bytes per color. When you switched over, now it counts 3 bytes per color, and pads in a n extra byte. So it is more correct, but uses 33% more memory. If these numbers seem to match what you see then that should be it

Comment: Another thing I just found out: all the decompressed images are colored as copied images if I use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast. But it weren't colored using kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst. Is it possible the reason of using more memory is because kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast copies images

Comment: @Jensen That is interesting, and no I have no idea what might cause that. I feel like they should both be copied versions since a new CGImage is created in the process. There might be some crazy optimizations under there that I know nothing of, sorry :(

Comment: Turns out I used the wrong flag. Using kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst solves all the issues. Thanks for your help :]

Comment: @Jensen, your last comment was important.

Answer (score 8):

Same result but less code and things to worry about:

```swift
func removeAlpha(from inputImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.init()
    format.opaque = true //Removes Alpha Channel
    format.scale = inputImage.scale //Keeps original image scale.
    let size = inputImage.size
    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format).image { _ in
        inputImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes pngData nil

Comment: Works like a charm when trying to compare PNG images represented as data and fetched from a view to be compared in a unit test. As long as Alpha is stripped for both stored image's pngData and fetched from a ImageView image's pngData, this makes the tests pass. Thanks, Justin!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer of @Justin Ganzer in a nice extension format for chainability:

```swift
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension UIImage {
    func removingAlpha() -> UIImage {
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.opaque = true // removes Alpha Channel
        format.scale = scale // keeps original image scale
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format).image { _ in
            draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -10):

```
-(void)JhagRemoveMethodRepet
{

    switch (Jhagtag)
    {
        case 1:
        {

            if (jhag1.alpha>0.3)
            {
                float alpha1;
                alpha1=jhag1.alpha;
                jhag1.alpha=alpha1-0.1;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"Mid"];
            }else
            {
            jhag1.alpha=0.0;
            [JRemovetimer invalidate];
             JRemovetimer=nil;
            [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"No"];
            [self checkcompeletewater];
            }

        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {

            if (jhag2.alpha>0.3)
            {
                float alpha1;
                alpha1=jhag2.alpha;
                jhag2.alpha=alpha1-0.1;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"Mid"];

                if (jhagBrush==YES)
                {
                    BTooth2.alpha=0.0;
                }
            }else
            {
                jhag2.alpha=0.0;
                [JRemovetimer invalidate];
                JRemovetimer=nil;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"No"];
                [self checkcompeletewater];
            }

        }
            break;
        case 3:
        {

            if (jhag3.alpha>0.3)
            {
                float alpha1;
                alpha1=jhag3.alpha;
                jhag3.alpha=alpha1-0.1;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:@"Mid"];
            }else
            {
                jhag3.alpha=0.0;
                [JRemovetimer invalidate];
                JRemovetimer=nil;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:@"No"];
                [self checkcompeletewater];
            }

        }
            break;
        case 4:
        {
            if (jhag4.alpha>0.3)
            {
                float alpha1;
                alpha1=jhag4.alpha;
                jhag4.alpha=alpha1-0.1;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:@"Mid"];
                if (jhagBrush==YES)
                {
                    BTooth3.alpha=0.0;
                    SpiderMud.alpha=0.0;
                }
            }else
            {
                jhag4.alpha=0.0;
                [JRemovetimer invalidate];
                JRemovetimer=nil;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:@"No"];
                [self checkcompeletewater];
            }

        }
            break;
        case 5:
        {

            if (jhag5.alpha>0.3)
            {
                float alpha1;
                alpha1=jhag5.alpha;
                jhag5.alpha=alpha1-0.1;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:4 withObject:@"Mid"];
            }else
            {
                jhag5.alpha=0.0;
                [JRemovetimer invalidate];
                JRemovetimer=nil;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:4 withObject:@"No"];
                [self checkcompeletewater];
            }

        }
            break;
        case 6:
        {
            if (jhag6.alpha>0.3)
            {
                float alpha1;
                alpha1=jhag6.alpha;
                jhag6.alpha=alpha1-0.1;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:5 withObject:@"Mid"];
                if (jhagBrush==YES)
                {
                    GreenMud.alpha=0.0;
                }
            }else
            {
                jhag6.alpha=0.0;
                [JRemovetimer invalidate];
                JRemovetimer=nil;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:5 withObject:@"No"];
                [self checkcompeletewater];
            }

        }
            break;
        case 7:
        {
            if (jhag7.alpha>0.3)
            {
                float alpha1;
                alpha1=jhag7.alpha;
                jhag7.alpha=alpha1-0.1;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:6 withObject:@"Mid"];
            }else
            {
                jhag7.alpha=0.0;
                [JRemovetimer invalidate];
                JRemovetimer=nil;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:6 withObject:@"No"];
                [self checkcompeletewater];
            }

        }
            break;
        case 8:
        {
            if (jhag8.alpha>0.3)
            {
                float alpha1;
                alpha1=jhag8.alpha;
                jhag8.alpha=alpha1-0.1;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:7 withObject:@"Mid"];

                if (jhagBrush==YES)
                {
                    BTooth1.alpha=0.0;
                }
            }else
            {
                jhag8.alpha=0.0;
                [JRemovetimer invalidate];
                JRemovetimer=nil;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:7 withObject:@"No"];
                [self checkcompeletewater];
            }

        }
            break;
        case 9:
        {
            if (jhag9.alpha>0.3)
            {
                float alpha1;
                alpha1=jhag9.alpha;
                jhag9.alpha=alpha1-0.1;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:8 withObject:@"Mid"];
            }
            else
            {
                jhag9.alpha=0.0;
                [JRemovetimer invalidate];
                JRemovetimer=nil;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:8 withObject:@"No"];
                [self checkcompeletewater];
            }

        }
            break;
        case 10:
        {
            if (jhag10.alpha>0.3)
            {
                float alpha1;
                alpha1=jhag10.alpha;
                jhag10.alpha=alpha1-0.1;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:9 withObject:@"Mid"];
            }else
            {
                jhag10.alpha=0.0;
                [JRemovetimer invalidate];
                JRemovetimer=nil;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:9 withObject:@"No"];
                [self checkcompeletewater];
            }

        }
            break;
        case 11:
        {
            if (jhag11.alpha>0.3)
            {
                float alpha1;
                alpha1=jhag11.alpha;
                jhag11.alpha=alpha1-0.1;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:10 withObject:@"Mid"];
                if (jhagBrush==YES)
                {
                    Yellowmud.alpha=0.0;
                }
            }else
            {
                jhag11.alpha=0.0;
                [JRemovetimer invalidate];
                JRemovetimer=nil;
                [Checkjhag replaceObjectAtIndex:10 withObject:@"No"];
                [self checkcompeletewater];
            }

        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}

-(void)checkcompeletewater
{
    NSMutableArray *compeletearr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"No",@"No",@"No",@"No",@"No",@"No",@"No",@"No",@"No",@"No",@"No", nil];


    if ([Checkjhag isEqualToArray:compeletearr] && jhagBrush==YES)
    {
        waterClean=YES;
        [self SoundPlay:@"puzzle_right"];
```

Comment: Add some comments in the code and explain it. Currently it is a bit disaster.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted. I can't say I entirely disagree here.)